# oracle sql multiple sum function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query with multiple `SUM`s that is giving me higher values than I expect. If I cut the query down to just one `SUM` everything works fine, but as soon as I add the other `SUM`s I get incorrect values. I've tried looking online and tried different approaches including changing the `JOIN`s and nested `SELECT`s, but still no luck. All help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT
    A.WR_NO WORK_ORDER, A.WR_TYPE_CODE WR_TYPE, B.NAME PLANNER, A.SCHEDULING_POLYGON_CODE AREA, A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE COMPLETION_DATE, C.ACTUAL_ITEM_AMT EST_ENG,
    SUM(D.AFTER_COND_FCT_AMT) EST_CREW, SUM(E.AFTER_COND_FCT_AMT) ASB_CREW, SUM(F.AFTER_COND_FCT_AMT) EST_CONTR, SUM(G.AFTER_COND_FCT_AMT) ASB_CONTR
FROM
    WORK_REQUEST A, CC.ALL_PEOPLE B, WR_CONTRIBUTION_VOUCHER C, WR_COST_ESTIMATE D, WR_COST_ESTIMATE E, WR_COST_ESTIMATE F, WR_COST_ESTIMATE G
WHERE
    (A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('10/01/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('10/04/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'))
    AND A.ENTRY_PERSON_NO = B.PERSON_NO(+)
    AND A.WR_NO = C.WR_NO(+)
    AND A.WR_NO = D.WR_NO(+)
    AND A.WR_NO = E.WR_NO(+)
    AND A.WR_NO = F.WR_NO(+)
    AND A.WR_NO = G.WR_NO(+)
    AND (C.VOUCHER_CNTRB_TYPE_CODE(+) = 'ENGT')
    AND (D.COST_TYPE_CODE(+) = 'LAB' AND D.DESIGN_ASBUILT_DA(+) = 'D' AND   D.PROVIDER(+) = 'CO')
    AND (E.COST_TYPE_CODE(+) = 'LAB' AND E.DESIGN_ASBUILT_DA(+) = 'A' AND   E.PROVIDER(+) = 'CO')
    AND (F.COST_TYPE_CODE(+) = 'LAB' AND F.DESIGN_ASBUILT_DA(+) = 'F' AND   F.PROVIDER(+) = 'CN')
    AND (G.COST_TYPE_CODE(+) = 'LAB' AND G.DESIGN_ASBUILT_DA(+) = 'G' AND   G.PROVIDER(+) = 'CN')
GROUP BY
    A.WR_NO, A.WR_TYPE_CODE, B.NAME, A.SCHEDULING_POLYGON_CODE, A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE,     C.ACTUAL_ITEM_AMT
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: I should improve the formatting of your question.

Comment: Do you have any values to test with or an example of what the "incorrect values" are?

Comment: With the single SUM, I get 3 'WORK_ORDER' values with respective 'EST_CREW' values of 256.06, .0248, 617.52. With the multiple SUM's I get 'EST_CREW' respective values of 1024.24, .0248, 2470.08.

Comment: I should add that using the single-SUM query without the SUM function yields the first values of 186, 15.5, 4.96, 49.6 which equals 256.06. Second values of 0.0248 which equals 0.0248. And third values of 186, 248, 93, 90.52 which equals the 617.52.

Comment: Which leads me to believe there is something wrong with my joins since the correct values are 'the correct sum value * the number of non-summed returned values = the incorrect multiple-sum values'

Answer (score 0):

You are getting higher values than you expect because the joins are multiplyinjg rows.  Without understanding the data structures, it is hard for an outside person to tell you exactly where the problem lies.

The solution to the problem is to do the sum *only on the table needed for calculating it*.  You can then join in additional tables/summaries after that point.

By the way, you really should be using proper `JOIN` syntax.  Use of the comma to imply a join is quite outdated and makes it harder to understand the query.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. So after some more reading online and taking heed of the suggestions, I got it to work by using the UNION function instead of the (+) joins. Here is my final code just in case it could help someone else. I'm new to SQL so there is definitely a cleaner way of doing this I assume:

Answer (score 0):

SELECT

```
WO_ID WORK_ORDER,
WR_TYPE_CODE WR_TYPE,
NAME PLANNER,
SCHEDULING_POLYGON_CODE AREA,
FINAL_CLOSE_DATE COMPLETE_DATE,
SUM (EENG) AS "ENG_TIME",
SUM (ECREW) AS "EST_CREW",
SUM (ACREW) AS "ASB_CREW",
SUM (ECONT) AS "EST_CONTR",
SUM (ACONT) AS "ASB_CONTR"
```

FROM

```
(SELECT
    A.WO_ID,
    A.WR_TYPE_CODE,
    B.NAME,
    A. SCHEDULING_POLYGON_CODE,
    A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE,
    C.ACTUAL_ITEM_AMT AS "EENG",
    0 "ECREW",
    0 "ACREW",
    0 "ECONT",
    0 "ACONT"
FROM
    WORK_REQUEST A,
    CC.ALL_PEOPLE B,
    WR_CONTRIBUTION_VOUCHER C
WHERE
    (A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('10/01/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('10/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'))
    AND A.ENTRY_PERSON_NO = B.PERSON_NO
    AND A.WR_NO = C.WR_NO
    AND (C.VOUCHER_CNTRB_TYPE_CODE = 'ENGT')
```

UNION

```
SELECT
    A.WO_ID,
    A.WR_TYPE_CODE,
    B.NAME,
    A. SCHEDULING_POLYGON_CODE,
    A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE,
    0 "EENG",
    D.AFTER_COND_FCT_AMT AS "ECREW",
    0 "ACREW",
    0 "ECONT",
    0 "ACONT"
FROM
    WORK_REQUEST A,
    CC.ALL_PEOPLE B,
    WR_COST_ESTIMATE D
WHERE
    (A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('10/01/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('10/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'))
    AND A.ENTRY_PERSON_NO = B.PERSON_NO
    AND A.WR_NO = D.WR_NO
    AND (D.COST_TYPE_CODE = 'LAB' AND D.DESIGN_ASBUILT_DA = 'D' AND D.PROVIDER = 'CO')
```

UNION

```
SELECT
    A.WO_ID,
    A.WR_TYPE_CODE,
    B.NAME,
    A. SCHEDULING_POLYGON_CODE,
    A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE,
    0 "EENG",
    0 "ECREW",
    E. AFTER_COND_FCT_AMT AS "ACREW",
    0 "ECONT",
    0 "ACONT"
FROM
    WORK_REQUEST A,
    CC.ALL_PEOPLE B,
    WR_COST_ESTIMATE E
WHERE
    (A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('10/01/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('10/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'))
    AND A.ENTRY_PERSON_NO = B.PERSON_NO
    AND A.WR_NO = E.WR_NO
    AND (E.COST_TYPE_CODE = 'LAB' AND E.DESIGN_ASBUILT_DA = 'A' AND E.PROVIDER = 'CO')
```

UNION

```
SELECT
    A.WO_ID,
    A.WR_TYPE_CODE,
    B.NAME,
    A. SCHEDULING_POLYGON_CODE,
    A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE,
    0 "EENG",
    0 "ECREW",
    0 "ACREW",
    F.AFTER_COND_FCT_AMT AS "ECONT",
    0 "ACONT"
FROM
    WORK_REQUEST A,
    CC.ALL_PEOPLE B,
    WR_COST_ESTIMATE F
WHERE
    (A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('10/01/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('10/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'))
    AND A.ENTRY_PERSON_NO = B.PERSON_NO
    AND A.WR_NO = F.WR_NO
    AND (F.COST_TYPE_CODE = 'LAB' AND F.DESIGN_ASBUILT_DA = 'D' AND F.PROVIDER = 'CN')
```

UNION

```
SELECT
    A.WO_ID,
    A.WR_TYPE_CODE,
    B.NAME,
    A. SCHEDULING_POLYGON_CODE,
    A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE,
    0 "EENG",
    0 "ECREW",
    0 "ACREW",
    0 "ECONT",
    G.AFTER_COND_FCT_AMT AS "ACONT"
FROM
    WORK_REQUEST A,
    CC.ALL_PEOPLE B,
    WR_COST_ESTIMATE G
WHERE
    (A.FINAL_CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('10/01/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('10/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'))
    AND A.ENTRY_PERSON_NO = B.PERSON_NO
    AND A.WR_NO = G.WR_NO
    AND (G.COST_TYPE_CODE = 'LAB' AND G.DESIGN_ASBUILT_DA = 'A' AND G.PROVIDER = 'CN'))
```

GROUP BY

```
WO_ID, WR_TYPE_CODE, NAME, SCHEDULING_POLYGON_CODE, FINAL_CLOSE_DATE
```

ORDER BY
    1 ASC